# How often should we poll the 74HC165 if we wish to detect 'button' presses?

Tags: esp32, shift-register

I am going to either chain 4 shift registers, or connect 4 shift registers to an ESP32 that is connected to a computer with bluetooth.

I understand at 3.3 volts, the 74HC165 can run at a clock speed of up to 18mhz. (5mhz at 2v, 25mhz at 4v).

What is normal for monitoring events on the shift registers? Is it normal to endlessly poll the shift registers? Or is a short delay between each read possible and/or desirable?

I cant imagine a reason for wanting to check for "events" (button presses, etc...) 1 million times per second. We could I guess, I just don't know if we should.

(I am new to the ESP32, so I am not sure how maintaining a bluetooth connection impacts things)

Comment: your question can easily be answered by you running some test code and pressing buttons ... it's not a question about Arduino, so it is off topic here ... questions about optimum sampling intervals belong at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I was going to ask why this downvoted (I dont really understand why) but then I looked at the "Top questions" tab and see most questions are downvoted ‍♂️

Comment: it was probably downvoted because the Arduino is irrelevant to your question ... you could be using a PIC chip or a PC or a Raspberry Pi or any of the many development boards and your question would not change

Comment: @jsotola Im not sure if thats true though? I didn't think I was asking an electronics question, because I am not sure how bluetooth and other activities on the ESP32 impact or don't impact reading from the chip. (For example, I don't know if reading from the buttons is interrupted by bluetooth events? Maybe it does? Maybe it doesnt? I just don't know what I dont know about programming these things yet.)

Answer (score 3):

For this you can employ the *nyquist-shannon* theory for signal sampling.

In short it states that "to sample a signal frequency of X you need at least 2x X samples per second".

So if you know how long a button will be pressed for (or released for, whichever is faster, i.e., the "highest frequency component of interest") then you know you need to sample with an interval of *at most half* that time.

So for a button that you may press for 100ms you know you need to sample at most every 50ms, preferably faster.

Comment: Thank you! that gives me a logical way to think through the numbers. The only thing that is not clear, then, from an electronics perspective (battery consumption, EMF, etc... ) do people tend to sample as infrequently as possible, or will the ESP32/74HC165 use basically the same power either way?   

(Apologies if these are basic questions, I am primarily a coder, enjoying exploring building basic electronic devices)

Comment: @Jay most people don't over think it unless they're doing something battery operated with sleep modes. As long as you do it fast enough just do whatever makes sense for your program. It makes no difference from a power consumption perspective unless you're sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty normal to endlessly poll the buttons. Even the original NES controller did it exactly that way, its protocol works exactly like you'd talk to a shift register. [Majenko alredy gave an answer on a good polling frequency](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/89881/55698), here's the additional hardware you'd need to work with interrupts instead of polling:

You'd need to add a bunch of OR gates (or AND gates if your buttons pull down instead of up) in "parallel" to your shift registers, so that you've got one signal with the semantics "(at least) one of the buttons have been pressed".

This signal then can be connected to the SH/LD input of your shift registers, triggering the shift registers to load (i.e. sample and hold) the inputs. In addition, it needs to be connected to one GPIO of your Arduino/ESP, to which you connect an interrupt handler on the software side. That interrupt handler then polls the shift register once (or sets a flag that causes your main loop to poll it). You may need an additional gate and GPIO to allow the polling routine to keep SH/LD HIGH while polling, depending on your use case and how bouncy your buttons are.

You could even use that signal to wake the ESP from deep sleep, poll the buttons once, do whatever needs to be done as a reaction to that button, then go back to deep sleep.

In conclusion: Endless polling is mostly the way to go, because of the hardware overhead to implement an interrupt solution.